# Mail chimp unsubscribes directly without confirmation page

Tags: mailchimp

I have the email marketing setup for the newsletter with mailchimp. When the subscribers get the email there is a standard static footer added by mailchimp automatically.

This has an unsubscribe link which directly unsubscribed the users without asking for confirmation email step.

I would like to have another step to confirm with user as this happens even with a forwarded email it removes the user from the subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way around for this, remove the |UNSUB| merge tag from your email footer and add custom **Unsubscribe Form URL**.

You can get your custom **Unsubscribe Form URL**, from the List you want it for.

*Choose the list -> Signup Forms -> Form Builder -> Unsubscribe Form* (choose this from Forms and Response emails drop down)

This will ask users to provide their email address to unsubscribe from the list.

**Edit:** This have a disadvantage of asking user email again and confirming the same, I will also suggest to remove |UNSUB| and use |UPDATE_PROFILE| (which have unsubscribe option with updating preference, user may change their mind)

Hope this will help.

Comment: I used the first technique, added Unsubscribe Form URL to the link in footer.

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam : Glad to know it helped you :)